# Обязательно ли вызвать deleteCookies("JSESSIONID") после выхода из сайта?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

В `SecurityFilterChain` у меня есть такая настройка:

```
.logout((logout) -> logout.logoutUrl("/logout")
                   .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                   .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                   .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID"))
```

После выхода пользователя её сессия инвалидируется и удаляется куки под названием *JSESSIONID*.

**Предположим, что операции `deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")` нет.**

Насколько мне известно, инвалидация сессии предполагает маркировку этой сессии как невалидной (устаревшой), и, если пользователь заново попытается с этой же сессией получить доступ к сайту, то сервер узнает, что эта сессия невалидна и сгенерирует для пользователя другую и присвоет *JSESSIONID* новое значение сессии.

Вопрос: Почему же я в почти каждом примере вижу, что после инвалидации сессии следует удаление *JSESSIONID*? Я имею ввиду, обязательно ли это действие и почему везде делают так.

Answer (score 0):

Удалять куки "JSESSIONID" после инвалидации сессии рекомендуется из соображений безопасности. Несмотря на то, что инвалидация сессии помечает её как недействительную, куки с идентификатором сессии могут все еще быть доступны  в браузере

[Статья на Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session)

Comment: Да, но при повторном обращении на сайт в JSESSIONID будет присвоено новое значение.

Comment: Если злоумышленник сумеет перехватить ее и воспользоваться, то сможет продолжать имитировать сеанс пользователя на сайте.

Comment: Каким образом злоумышленник будет использовать невалидную сессию?

Comment: Возможно, чтобы провести session fixation атаку, или что нибудь в этом роде, думаю, Вам стоит обратиться к соответствующей литературе